# Make this scrape more neat?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code scrapes a webpage. Each entry is identified per row on the webpage.

However, I am not able to find something that delimits each row. I scrape all the titles (which works fine as there is only 1 unique title per row)

but for fields such as "Chair" there can be multiple per row, and my code has no way to distinguish which data came from which row.

For example - Row 2 on the webpage - Has multiple people in chair, and my code does not distinguish who came from what row/title.

Is there a way to modify my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import pandas as pd

driver.get('https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2021/session_search.cfm?_ga=2.259773066.1015449088.1617295032-97934194.1617037074')
page_source = driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')

eachTitle=soup.find_all('span',class_='session-title')
for item in eachTitle:
    print(item.text.strip())
eachChair=soup.find_all('span',class_='session-speaker-name')
for j in eachChair:
    print(j.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the ordering of presentations you can just use beautifulsoup without the overhead of a browser. The css selectors work such that you identify the target rows by the ones that have a child with class `heading` and the immediately adjacent row. It's possible you can alter the selectors to preserve order.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_source = requests.get('https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2021/session_search.cfm?_ga=2.259773066.1015449088.1617295032-97934194.1617037074').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')

for session in soup.select('tr:has(.heading), tr:has(.heading) + tr'):
    print(session.select_one('a strong').text.strip())  
    
    for speaker in session.select('.session-speaker'):
        role = speaker.select_one('.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
        name = speaker.select_one('.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
        print(role, name)
    
    print('labels: ', [i.text.strip() for i in session.select('.session-track-label')])
    print()
```

Comment: Would this also get the topics? (For example in row 1 above "Speaker" we have "Presidential Session" and "Community Psychiatry"

Comment: topics added to answer